# Juice Jacking Detection: Detect all usb devices / accessories (flash drive, keyboard, cables, computer, etc.) connected to the android device

Tags: android, security, android-security

What is Juice Jacking:

- https://www.fcc.gov/juice-jacking-tips-to-avoid-it
- https://www.arcyber.army.mil/Portals/34/Fact%20Sheets/Juice%20Jacking/ARCYBER%20fact%20sheet%20-%20Juice%20Jacking%20(13%20Apr2022).pdf?ver=n1VMqM2r0u8pswYee2OPLQ%3D%3D

In order to notify the users for any possible Juice Jacking attempt I am trying to detect any piece of hardware (malicious cable, computer, flash drive, etc.) attached to the Android device and alert the user that their Android device is connected to anything else other than a wall charger.

Basically, I want to notify the user when a device or accessory with data transfer capabilities or a keyboard connects to their devices.

I tried to use broadcast receivers for the following:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host

```
BroadcastReceiver usb_device_intent_broadcast_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                Log.d("Extras", key + " : " + (bundle.get(key) != null ? bundle.get(key) : "NULL"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Extras", "NULL");

        }
    }
};

String usbAccessoryAttachedAction = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED";
IntentFilter filter_usb_accessory_attached_receiver = new IntentFilter(usbAccessoryAttachedAction);
mContext.registerReceiver(usb_device_intent_broadcast_receiver, filter_usb_accessory_attached_receiver);

String usbDeviceAttachedAction = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED";
IntentFilter filter_usb_device_attached_receiver = new IntentFilter(usbDeviceAttachedAction);
mContext.registerReceiver(usb_device_intent_broadcast_receiver, filter_usb_device_attached_receiver);

String usbStateChangeAction = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE";
IntentFilter filter_usb_device_state_receiver = new IntentFilter(usbStateChangeAction);
mContext.registerReceiver(usb_device_intent_broadcast_receiver, filter_usb_device_state_receiver);
```

With this approach, I am able to receive intents each time a USB state change happens.

I am not sure if this is the right approach. Anyone tried something similar?